# Displaying HTML from DB in <h:outputText escape="false"> results in broken HTML page

Tags: html, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

Is there any way to setup Firefox and Chrome to work with escape=false attribute in h:outputText tag. When there is some html that needs to be shown in the browser, Firefox and Chrome show parsed string correctly, but any other links in application are freezed (??).

The example html from db:

```
<HEAD>
<BASE href="http://"><META content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv=Content-Type>          
<LINK rel=stylesheet type=text/css href=""><META name=GENERATOR content="MSHTML 9.00.8112.16434">
</HEAD>
<BODY><FONT color=#000000 size=2 face="Segoe UI">läuft nicht</FONT></BODY>
```

Parsed HTML on the page:

läuft nicht

What is very weird, is that in IE everything works (usually it is opposite).

I use primefaces components (v2.2), .xhtml, tomcat 7 and JSF 2.0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You end up with syntactically [invalid](http://validator.w3.org/) HTML this way:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <head></head>
        <body>...</body>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is not right. There can be only one `<head>` and `<body>`. The browsers will behave unspecified. You need to remove the *entire* `<head>` and the wrapping `<body>` from that HTML so that you end up with *only*

```
<FONT color=#000000 size=2 face="Segoe UI">läuft nicht</FONT>
```

You'd need to either update the DB to remove unnecessary HTML, or to use [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org) to parse this piece out on a per-request basis something like as follows:

```
String bodyContent = Jsoup.parse(htmlFromDB).body().html();
// ...
```

Alternatively, you could also display it inside a HTML `<iframe>` instead with help of a servlet. E.g.

```
<iframe src="htmlFromDBServlet?id=123"></iframe>
```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem:

1. Storing HTML in a DB is a terrible design.
2. If the HTML originates from user-controlled input, you've a huge XSS attack hole this way.
3. The `<font>` tag is *deprecated* since 1998.

Comment: The problem is that the data in the database are "corrupted" and there are a lot of data with this invalid HTML which I am not allowed to change. Also, I know that I can use mu own parser but I ask if there is any meta tag that I can use to solve this?

Comment: There is definitely not a meta tag for this. Either cleanup the DB or use a HTML parser like Jsoup to remove that clutter before presenting.

Comment: I haven't seen `<font>` in a very long time, and the capitalized markup brings back memories of HTML in the early to mid 90's.  This question came out of a time machine! :)

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you're trying to do something that JSF was not really meant to do.  Rather than try to insert HTML in your web page, you ought to try having the links already on your page and modifying the "rendered" attribute through an AJAX call.